no puedo conectar python con mysql-connector-python, sin embargo tampoco me sale ningún error de conexion
Estoy aprendiendo python.
Anteriormente conecte python con mysql  y me funcionó con normalidad.
Posteriormente hice un reset  mi dispositivo y se desinstalo mysql, python y vscode, por lo tanto tuve que instalar nuevamente en mi sistema operativo windows 11 64bits.
Sin embargo ahora ya no puedo conectar python con mysql usando el modulo de mysql- connector. pero tampoco me sale ningún error,  pareciera que no se estaría ejecutando el scrip. Lo cual es raro por que con pymysql si me conecta con normalidad.
Ya intente todo los modos y nada.
Alguien podría ayudarme?
De antemano muchas gracias.
desde la terminal de vscode con el scrip mysql -u root -p
puedo acceder con normalidad a realizar una consulta con mysql, pero ejecutando el archivo de python para conectar y hacer la consulta no devuelve ninguna respuesta, tampoco arroja un error.

Muestra como estás realizando la conexión nueva, y revisa el log de errores de mysql

Revisa que la instalación exista con pip show mysql-connector-python

en consola me sale asi: PS C:\Users\PC\Desktop\prueba2> & C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python313/python.exe c:/Users/PC/Desktop/prueba2/prueba33.py
Intentando conectar...
PS C:\Users\PC\Desktop\prueba2> pip show mysql -connector-python
Usage:
pip show [options]  ...
no such option: -c
PS C:\Users\PC\Desktop\prueba2>

perdon realice mal los comandos, en realidad me sale asi:

Name: mysql-connector-python
Version: 9.1.0
Summary: A self-contained Python driver for communicating with MySQL servers, using an API that is compliant with the Python Database API Specification v2.0 (PEP 249).
Home-page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/
Author: Oracle and/or its affiliates
Author-email:
License: GNU GPLv2 (with FOSS License Exception)
Location: C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:

Oks, recuerda agregarlos a la publicación con el botón editar. Ahora realiza una conexión desde python, y prueba a conectar, ve si obtienes un error, y sube ese código a la publicación igual.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
